# Visual Studio 2017 не включается "View White Space" а очень нужно

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Хочу чтобы отображались пробелы и табуляторы как [тут на втором скриншоте](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/04/09/view-white-space/):

вот он:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но описанный там способ не работает в 2017 студии, с помощью stackoverfollow нашел, что в 2017 это делается так:

Edit --> Advanced --> View White Space

Включил(выключал-включал, студию перезапускал) - не помогло как видно на скриншоте в голубом квадрате пробелы и табы не появились, дополнительно зеленым выделил где точно есть пробелы и табы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Верисия моей студии:
[image: Версия Visual Studio]

---

UPD1: Обновил студию до 15.6.3 и выбрал светлую тему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

UPD2: при отключении Resharper'а если в Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Tabs выбрано keep tabs становятся видны табы(а пробелы нет)

Comment: В Pro версии 15.6.2 отображается, но при темной цветовой схеме, почти не видно. При светлой-видно нормально

Comment: VS Community 2017 15.6.3 всё работает и отображается.

Comment: @SlavonDT Благодарю на мысль насчет цвета темы, попробовал Ligh и Blue темы, студию перезапускал - пробелы/табы не появились :-/

Comment: @Bulson обновил до 15.6.3, добавил 2 скриншота^^ пробелы/табы не появились :-/

Comment: может все дело в шрифтах?

Comment: после нажатия пункт становится выбранным?

Comment: @KoVadim поподробнее в какихшрифтах? у меня Windows 10 Корпоративная

Comment: @Grundy да пункт меню становиться выбранным. я его раз 10 уже снимал-ставил, перезапускал студию...

Comment: В шрифтах, которые использует студия. Ну мало чего там. я бы попробовал их поменять (поиграться:) )

Comment: ReSharper попробуйте отключить. Возможно дело именно в нем.

Comment: У меня работает данная штука даже в Resharper

Comment: @iluxa1810 да у многих работает. в это-то и вопрос.

Comment: @Jiraff537 попробуйте удалить решарпер целиком, а не просто отключить. и сбросить настройки студии после удаления (или просто студию под другим пользователем запустить)

Comment: @PashaPash а как именно настройки студии вы сбрасывать предлагаете? думаю я это хочу сделать.

Comment: @Jiraff537 из меню Tools / Import Export settings, или из командной строки - `Devenv /ResetSettings`

Comment: @PashaPash tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заработало!

На черном фоне точки еле заметны, но они там есть.

(что стало причиной сложно сказать: решарпер не удалил-только отключил, много лазил в Options-Editor-C#-Tabs менял с точек на табы и обратно включал и выключал решарпер и когда уже решил опустить руки вдруг оно заработало)

Всем спасибо за мысли!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]